# JavaScript call function not working - simple example

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a JavaScript function (plain old JS.. not jQuery or any other library) but i am having some issues. Seems simple but maybe i am doing something silly. I have a HTML element with an ID of testbutton. Here is my JavaScript..

```
document.getElementById("testbutton").onClick = function() { makeRequest('test.html'); };
function makeRequest(url) {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

Comment: `onClick` is an arbitrary property, you need `onclick`.

Comment: it is `onclick` no caps C

Comment: I knew it was something silly - thanks guys!

Comment: Will suggest to use console.log("something") to trace code flow. Or you may debug your code in browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's `onclick`, not `onClick`

```
document.getElementById("testbutton").onclick = function() { makeRequest('test.html'); };

function makeRequest(url) {
    alert('clicked');
}
```